# What proportion of a rockets fuel remains unburnt?

Tags: rockets, fuel, chemistry, combustion

Presumably liquid rocket combustion is never 100% efficient, so what proportion of fuel does typically remain unburnt, venting into the atmosphere, and does this vary for different rocket designs and fuel types - hydrogen, methane etc?

Comment: Accounting for what is leftover in the tanks or only the one which remain unburnt after passing through the engine ?

Comment: This varies for each engine design. An important factor is the mixture ratio, there's usually a slight excess of fuel over oxidizer.

Comment: Yes Antzi, I was really thinking about how much ends up in the atmosphere, but perhaps sources do in the end?   For hydrogen it's not a problem, but methane is an extremely strong greenhouse gas.

Comment: I think the incident of russian rocket falling  up over canadian island/waters rich waters. The hydrazine in tank burnt up but it wasn't regular rocket.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to track down one reference online, in the SSME (Shuttle) engine, which uses liquid hydrogen/oxygen, "two-stage combustion approximately 99.6% efficient"

http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2011/ph240/nguyen1/docs/SSME_PRESENTATION.pdf

Also see, Modern Engineering for Design of Liquid-Propellant Rocket Engines by Dieter K. Huzel